# "enough rice" or "rice enough"

Tags: word-order

> There was rice enough for all four of them.
>
> There was enough rice for all four of them.

Are these two sentences different in meaning as to the position of "enough"?

Comment: Both are correct and the meaning is the same, although the first is a little old-fashioned.

Answer (score 3):

When used before the noun that it qualifies, **enough** is a determiner, like **some**:

> There was **enough** rice for all four of them.
>   There was **some** rice for all four of them.

When used after what it qualifies, **enough** is an adverb of degree. As an adverb, it is normally used to qualify another adverb or an adjective:

> You are not running **quickly** enough. - *adverb*
>   The house was **big** enough for all four of them. - *adjective*

In modern usage it is normally only used to qualify a noun if you are using the noun in an adjectival sense:

> He is **man** enough for the job.

In your first sentence, **rice** is not used in an adjectival sense, so placing **enough** after it sounds somewhat old-fashioned:

> There was rice **enough** for all four of them.

Answer (score 0):

There's rice enough........

There's enough rice........

The usage of the determiner "enough" after a noun is old-fashioned.

Today, you use the "enough" in front of a noun, not after it. So you say:

There's enough rice......., not there's rice enough......

However, you use the enough as an adverb to modify an adjective or a verb.

The qunantity of the rice was large enough ..

He has eaten enough.

There's a common phrase "be man enough to do/for something".

In the phrase man has been used in the sense of "brave".

He was man enough to admit his mistake = He was brave enough to admit his mistake.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. However, you should [edit](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/111313/edit) your question to provide explanation and improve formatting. An answer with little or no explanation isn't great at helping someone learn the language.

Comment: A man is an adult male person as opposed to a teenager, so my take is that it is this that makes adult enough a person man enough to admit his mistake, not his braveness. IMHO

Comment: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-man-enough-to-do-something-for-something

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-man-enough-to-do-sth